# How can I effectively decrease my heart rate (during and after exercise)?

Tags: cardio, health-risk, heart-rate

I often have a very high heart rate when doing cardiovascular exercise even if I try to keep low intensity when doing it.

I mostly run or swim and I would like to be able to keep a lower heart rate while doing exercise. Also, sometimes I feel a bit dizzy if I stop suddenly the exercise without decreasing the intensity bit by bit.

Furthermore, my heart rate doesn't decrease very fast when I finish the exercise.

It is decreasing slowly over time when I keep doing exercise in a regular basis but I would like to know **if there are any tips to keep my heart rate lower when doing exercise and to get back to a normal heart rate afterwards**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways, but first figure out what the dizziness feeling is or at least make sure your training with someone else who knows they need to keep an eye on you. I cant think of a time I was dizzy after stopping fast, so that would scare me. So you know, to compare, my heart rate doesn't drop too fast after a certain point. After training at 160 bpm it will drop to 130 quickly then 110 after 30-60 seconds maybe then down lower over the next 5-10 minutes. My resting heart rate is 45 bpm which is different from most people in the same shape that I am in.

One you should incorporate some high intensity workouts in your routine. Sprint for 10-20 minutes at a time. Go all out for 5-10 minutes. I do this for running so swimming may have a little difference in the timing.

Two you need to find out what low intensity means. You can do this by using heart rate monitors and defining what each zone means. For example, when your entering the aerobic zone this means that your breathing rate is just starting to be more than normal. See the chart [here](https://www.mcmillanrunning.com/articlePages/article/3) for more reliable information. Another way to do this is by running with someone to help them start out running which will force you to their slower pace, force your self to slow down using a watch, or take very short and slow strides to do a lazy jog.

Comment: Just a note: There is no "aerobic zone", it's all aerobic (Unless you're sprinting, anaerobic doesn't last more than 10-20 seconds in most cases). What varies is the the percentages of where your fuel for the exercise is coming from, and even that is in portions of both sources depending on intensity.

Comment: Agree for sure. Thats why I pointed to a McMillan chart because he does a good job of characterizing each section or zone while pointing out the same things your saying. Plus this would be a discussion that is kind of a tangent going off topic.

Comment: I know, I have an appointment with my doctor this Friday and a friend told me that I should have something called ortostatic hypotension and that it should be harmless, I'll ask anyway. I will take into account the idea of adding high intensity workouts, thanks.